# What is the actual function of the third torch in the comparator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have heard different explanations for what the function of the third torch is in the comparator.

[image: Comparator]

But I have never gotten a definite answer for what the use is being able to right click on the comparator and this third torch comes up. What is its actual function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the front torch is off, the comparator extends the back signal, but if the side input is stronger (and not equal) the front signal will be off.

When the front torch is on, the output will be the back input minus the side input, and will of course be off if the side input is equal or greater.